# Entity Framework Syntax for IN clause with subquery

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

I want a Entity Framework sql syntax for `IN` clause with subquery..
My original syntax is like

```
Select * from Table1 where Table1.id in (select table2.id from Table2 where 1=1)
```

I tried to write this like below:

```
"SELECT VALUE pkg_outer from 
   (SELECT distinct(pkg) from ExploitaEntities.mst_package as pkg  WHERE 1=1 
   AND pkg.package_id in 
   (SELECT VALUE dtl_outer FROM(select distinct(dtl.package_id) from ExploitaEntities.mst_pkg_detail as dtl where 1=1)) 
   as dtl_outer) 
as pkg_outer"
```

but it is giving me error as below:

```
"The element type 'Edm.Int32' and the CollectionType 'Transient.collection[Transient.rowtype[(package_id,Edm.Int32(Nullable=True,DefaultValue=))](Nullable=True,DefaultValue=)]' 
 are not compatible. The IN expression only supports entity, primitive, and reference types.  
 Near IN set expression,..."
```

Comment: Your example doesn't show Entity Framework being used.  Where is the EF code?

Comment: You don't need the `SELECT VALUE dtl_outer FROM(` part.

Comment: It is entity framework only. have used plain sql instead of LINQ code but using entity database model only

Answer (score 1):

```
dbContext.TableName.Where(x => x.ColumnName.Value == "Test")
```

Reference the Table in your Db context. You can set a condition for every record that is read.

Comment: How can this useful for IN clause?

Comment: This translates to:   `SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE COLUMNNAME IN ('Test')`

Comment: ok got your point..
but i need some thing like sub query in my in clause..

SELECT * FROM TABLE NAME WHERE COUMNNAME IN (SELECT COUMN FROM OTHER TABLE)

Thanks a lot

Comment: `dbContext.TableName.Where(x => x.ColumnName.Value == dbContext.Table2.Where(y => y.Column2.Value == "test2").First().ToString())`

Untested, but give it a shot.